# Get python data in an html/javascript webpage

Tags: python, jquery, json

So I'm trying to make a problem for a ctf, and for a problem, I need to send data from a python script to the javascript. Can anyone tell me how?

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="text">text</h1>
        <script>
            $.get("[website]/cgi-bin/challenge.py", 
                function(data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I replaced the website with [website]. 
The python code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
json.dumps("It works!")
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: There I added the code I tried. Sorry about that - I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

text = json.dumps("It works!")

print "Content-Type: application/json\n"
print text
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try: https://www.zerorpc.io/ , zerorpc is a communication between server-side processes that lets you transfer data from a server to a client.

in your situation, if you want to transfer data from python to node.js you cand do it like this:

in your python file as a server do:

```
import zerorpc

class HelloRPC(object):
def hello(self, name):
    return "Hello, %s" % name

s = zerorpc.Server(HelloRPC())
s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
s.run()
```

and in your node.js code as a client:

```
 var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");

 var client = new zerorpc.Client();
 client.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

 client.invoke("hello", "RPC", function(error, res, more) {
   console.log(res);
 });
```

this will print "hello RPC" on the console.

Comment: I need to sent the data from the python to the client side javascript, so I can change something on the website - I don't want it to print it to the console.